# Unable to pass multiple series using dual y axis in highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I need to pass multiple series in highcharts using dual y axis. I have the data in a series0 array getting dynamically from php.

It is working as follows when using single y axis

```
series:series0
```

but when i use dual y axis i need to pass the array in data: series0. But its not working as it is multiple series

I have tried

```
series: {
//data : series0
data: JSON.parse("[" + series0 + "]")
}
```

It doesn't work.Please help to solve

Comment: what does the series0 look like

Comment: HI Sir thanks for your input.i am passing the data into array as follows.
var k = 0;var category0 = new Array();var data0 = new Array();var series0 = new Array();var strarr = new Array();
  for(var i=0;i<str.length-1;i++){
   var strarr = str[i].split('$');
   category0[k] = strarr[0];data0[k] = strarr[1].split('|').join(',');
   series0[k] = {name: category0[k],data: JSON.parse("[" + data0[k] + "]") };
   k++;
  }

Comment: can you paste the exact data section with values which is assigned

Comment: Please attach a data0k array and others which you use in your loop.

Comment: finding little difficulty to print data0k, i am putting the data here of var strarr . legend1,11,11.,legend3,32,11,32,legend4,6|6|6,11,32,6,6,6,legend7,0|0|0,11,32,6,6,6,0,0,0,legend8,8|9|12,11,32,6,6,6,0,0,0,8,9,12,legend10,31|31|34,11,32,6,6,6,0,0,0,8.708,9,12,31,31,34,legend11,7|7|7,11,32,6,6,6,0,0,0,8,9,12,31,31,34,7,7,7,

Comment: There does not appear to be anything there that is usable as data for a highcharts series.  I think you'll need to 1) read the Highcharts documentation on data - http://www.highcharts.com/docs/ ,  and 2) start your question over with a lot more detail and code showing what you are doing.